# Server 2012 R2 RDS "run away" memory, ghost processes, etc

Tags: rds

I have recently setup an RDS "all-in-one" box that is running all the necessary RDS components on the same box. I am having a big issue with ghost processes (LoginUI.exe, CSRSS.exe, etc.) that given about 12 hours will completely consume all 16GB I have allocated to this RDS VM.

16GB is more than enough to serve ~10 simultaneous connections. Users don't complain after a fresh boot of the server. I have about 30 total thin clients running OpenThinClient configured with FreeRDP to auto reconnect after app close (i.e. when a user disconnects from a session, it will automatically relaunch the FreeRDP client to prompt for a new login).

What I think is happening is effectively my thin clients are DDoSing my box. When FreeRDP connects and the standard Windows 8 style login screen appears, it will disconnect after about ~30 seconds of no activity. Once the server ends the connection, FreeRDP closes. But OpenThinClient will relaunch the FreeRDP client. This loop keeps going until a user logs in.

Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed all recommended hotfixes for RDS as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933664 ?